# equivalence of -d parameter in curl in httr package of R

Tags: r, curl, httr, opencpu

I'm following the [official manual](http://jeroenooms.github.io/opencpu-manual/opencpu-server.pdf) of `opencpu` package in R. In *chapter 4.3 Calling a function* It uses `curl` to test API:

```
curl http://your.server.com/ocpu/library/stats/R/rnorm -d "n=10&mean=100"
```

and the sample output is:

```
/ocpu/tmp/x032a8fee/R/.val
/ocpu/tmp/x032a8fee/stdout
/ocpu/tmp/x032a8fee/source
/ocpu/tmp/x032a8fee/console
/ocpu/tmp/x032a8fee/info
```

I can use `curl` to get similar result, but when I try to send this http request using `httr` package in R, I don't know how to replicate the result. Here is what I tried:

```
resp <- POST(
  url = "localhost/ocpu/library/stats/R/rnorm",
  body= "n=10&mean=100"
)
resp
```

the output is:

```
Response [HTTP://localhost/ocpu/library/stats/R/rnorm]
  Date: 2015-10-16 00:51
  Status: 400
  Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
  Size: 30 B
No Content-Type header found.
```

I guess I don't understand what's the equivalence of curl `-d` parameter in `httr`, how can I get it correct?

Comment: `body=list(n=106, mean=100)`

Comment: @Bamgf have you considered accepting answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :)

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

getFunctionEndPoint <- function(url, format) {
    return(paste(url, format, sep = '/'))
}

resp <- POST(
    url = getFunctionEndPoint(
        url = "https://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/library/stats/R/rnorm",
        format = "json"),
    body = list(n = 10, mean = 100), 
    encode = 'json')

fromJSON(rawToChar(resp$content))
```

Comment: Test yours by changing `url` from `"https://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/library/stats/R/rnorm"` to `"localhost/ocpu/library/stats/R/rnorm"`.